# Cannot replace Activity with Fragment

Tags: android, mobile, nullpointerexception

When I click the start button I want my activity to switch to a fragment. It gives me a nullpointer exception when I try to replace. Why is that?

I need some help really fast because I gonna hand this assignment in very soon.

```
package com.example.quizapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Fragment1 newFragment1;
    private FragmentTransaction ft;
    private Button startButton1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        startButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        startButton1.setOnClickListener(myhandler1);

        ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        newFragment1 = (Fragment1) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment1);

    }

    View.OnClickListener myhandler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ft.replace(R.layout.main, newFragment1);
        }
    };


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
02-07 20:56:06.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1902): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 20:56:06.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1902): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 20:56:06.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:394)
02-07 20:56:06.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:429)
02-07 20:56:06.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:421)
02-07 20:56:06.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at com.example.quizapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
02-07 20:56:06.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
02-07 20:56:06.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
02-07 20:56:06.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-07 20:56:06.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-07 20:56:06.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 20:56:06.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-07 20:56:06.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 20:56:06.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-07 20:56:06.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-07 20:56:06.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-07 20:56:06.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF" >

    <fragment 
        android:name="com.example.quiz.Fragment1"
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="startButtonClicked"
        android:text="Start quiz!" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Look at the errors now after I did what you said:

```
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.quizapp/com.example.quizapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at com.example.quizapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  ... 11 more
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.quiz.Fragment1: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4709)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  ... 21 more
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.quiz.Fragment1" on path: /data/app/com.example.quizapp-2.apk
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
02-07 23:19:50.171: E/AndroidRuntime(869):  ... 24 more
```

Comment: Well it shouldn't be. You want me to post the Fragment1.java class?

Comment: Make sure it isn't, otherwise there's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is the offending line;

```
ft.replace(R.layout.main, newFragment1);
```

The first argument of 'replace' must be an '**id**' not a 'layout'.
The 'id' must the the id of a View.

Without knowing how your layout-xml (main.xml) looks like, I can't tell you what a correct value for the first argument of 'replace' would be. Here is how your code could look like:

```
ft.replace(R.id.some_view_id, newFragment1);
```

You have same problem for this statement:

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment1);
```

again, R.layout.... is wrong. It should be R.**id**....

If you can show us your main.xml, we could help you better.

**Update after you showed your XML:**

Get rid of this statement in your onCreate:

```
ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Then replace this

```
newFragment1 = (Fragment1) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragment1);
```

with

```
newFragment1 = (Fragment1) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
```

and

replace this

```
ft.replace(R.layout.main, newFragment1);
```

with

```
ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment1, newFragment1).commit();
```

This may make your code not crash, but you'll replace the R.id.fragment1 with itself... no change. Where is the **new** fragment that you want to replace the old newFragment1 (since you found that one in onCreate)?

Comment: Look now. I edited the post so now should be able to see the main.xml file.

Comment: Make sure you have a class called Fragment1, that extends Fragment, in package com.example.quiz that has a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Provide it a tag with

```
ft.replace(R.layout.main, newFragment1, "my_new_awesome_frag");
```

That has fixed it in the past for me.

Answer (score 0):

you have not inflated your fragment . Read the documentation of [findFragmentById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById%28int%29)

It clearly states

**Returns**
**The fragment if found or null otherwise.**

Comment: There are many ways to add a fragment
1. add <fragment> tag in your activity layout and when the activity layout inflates it inflates the fragment also . 
2. Create a fragment class as you have done (Fragment1 i assume), in the create view make sure you have the following line 
inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
--> Finally add the fragment and commit the transaction 

 ft.add(R.id.myfragment, myFragment);
 ft.commit();

Comment: This didn't work. Or I couldnt make it work. Do you have Skype?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong with this code.  The first problem is that you can't replace a "static" fragment, with a "dynamic" fragment.  See:

http://portabledroid.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/programmatic-and-layout-fragments/#comments

The second problem is that you need to commit your transaction.  I suggest getting the transaction, doing the replace, and committing it, all in the onClick handler.  There is example code showing how to add and then replace a fragment, correctly, here:

https://github.com/marakana/yamba/tree/yambaII

Comment: ... and, btw, it looks like you don't actually have a fragment defined!  You need a class called "com.example.quiz.Fragment1" that extends fragment.

Answer (score -1):

This is my Fragment1.java class:

```
package com.example.quizapp;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);


    }
}
```